# At the end of Zootopia, are Nick Wilde and Judy Hopps an item?

Tags: zootopia

In true [buddy-buddy cop style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_cop_film), Nick and Judy start out as reluctant partners but    gradually learn to respect each other's unique qualities.

At the end (and presumably some months later), we have this scene in which Judy states that she *loves* Nick.

**Actual Dialogue from the clip:**

> **Nick:** *You know you love me.*
>
> **Judy:** *Do I know that?.....Yes I do.*

**Was this scene intended to imply a *romantic* connection between them?**

Comment: Related: [What is Judy's and Nick's relationship?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49264/49)

Comment: It would be really weird if they were in a relationship... I mean how exactly would that work anyhow?

Comment: @Rincewind - Well he's not that much taller than her and since none of the animals in Zootopia have genitals, I guess their relationship would be largely platonic anyway.

Comment: Well... there are baby creatures in Zootopia so I think that they managed somehow... @Valorum

Comment: @Rincewind - If it's good enough for [Kif Kroker](https://theinfosphere.org/Kif's_offspring), it's good enough for Zootopia.

Comment: I have now googled Kif Croker but... still not sure what he is... lol @Valorum

Comment: @Rincewind - His species propagate by genetic transfer via skin contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [film's co-director](https://twitter.com/ByronPHoward/status/717834585137000448), the answer is no, at least for the time being.

[image]

> 7. **Will there be a sequel?**
>      *We don't know yet. I can only answer this question when Disney decides what the answer will be.*
> 8. **Are Nick & Judy a romantic couple in Zootopia?**
>      ***They are friends.*** Their future relationship is undecided so far. See previous question

That being said, they're very clearly leaving the door open to the possibility.

Answer (score 7):

No, They most definitely aren't yet as already stated by Valorum. In addition to his comprehensive answer, there were initial plans on making this happen.

There was a deleted scene in the movie which was going to make it happen however, that scene did not make the final cut.

Twitter user @Nick_wyld tweeted at director Rich Moore an image from deviant art featuring Nick meeting Judy's parents and she introducing him as her boyfriend.

The [Image from Deviant art](http://img00.deviantart.net/73d1/i/2016/074/5/c/zootropia_alternative_ending__by_lyrin93-d9v7war.jpg) from [Lyrin93](http://lyrin93.deviantart.com/):

[image]

The [actual Tweet](https://twitter.com/nick_wyld/status/711629309300117505):

[image]

Rich Moore confirmed that there was a similar scene in the movie but it was later dropped. He also stated that it may be included in blu ray version.

Rich Moore's [actual tweet](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/711672117662720000?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw):

[image]

Director also confirmed the friends-only relationship of Judy and Nick when a fan asked him on Twitter:

[Actual Tweet](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/702848375121711104):

[image]

**UPDATE:** In Light of Valorum's finds on DVD, it appears that when Director said that there was a similar scene, he might not have meant completely similar with depiction of a romantic connection between the two characters. However, it is also possible that they did not add the said scene in Blu ray either as the director said they might include the scene but did not state that they will definitely do that. Nevertheless, the similarities between the supposed deleted scene and the extra scene valorum found are very convincing.

Comment: I'm watching the Bluray extras at the moment. I'll let you know if I find that deleted scene

Comment: @Valorum Cheers. That'd be great cus I don't have the extras.

Comment: I've just found the [scene they're referring to](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kyN9T.png). She's not brought him home as her boyfriend, she's brought him home to her apartment to keep him away from the mobsters chasing him. Her parents have arrived (unexpectedly) and seem horrified at the idea that she bringing a fox into her apartment and that he might be her boyfriend. She disavows them of this and states unequivocally that he's her *friend* and that he's helping her to solve a case.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe they never included such a scene on blu ray either as director said they might include it, he did not say they definitely will.

Comment: That's definitely the scene he's talking about in the tweet. The similarities are startling

Comment: You might be right. Your answer was correct anyways, they are not together.

Comment: No, in that scene Judy never outright _denied_ Nick's a boyfriend. Considering the timeline, he's most certainly _not yet_ her boyfriend, but her skirting her dad's direct question at the and can only be taken as "hedging her bets". She probably already had some feelings for him, but since it was much too early, she didn't commit to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Throughout the movie? No. They were not "an item".

Were they, at any time, behaved like "an item" *on-screen*? Definitely not.

Were they, at the end of the movie, "an item", even if they did not show a romantic relationship *on-screen*? *Very probably*.

I shall refer you to the list of ***official translations*** of "Nick's question":

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWRbkCai0K5NXbVHW0ZjBvxDdQGli-niYm2ul0j7uqQ/edit

(DO NOTE that the "Meaning" column was filled *based on research, talks & discussions* with person(s) of the respective ***culture***.)

At the time of me posting this answer:

- 9 (nine) translations have undoubted "romantic" meaning
- 2 (two) translations have ambiguous meaning (can be romantic, can be platonic)
- 3 (three) translations are still unclear (I cannot find people of those *culture* to discuss)

So, the *absolute majority* of the official translations declared that, at the end of the movie, they (have) became "an item".

Again, these are ***Official*** Translations. As heard in the cinema and/or written in the DVD/BD subtitles.